# Comparative Correlatives without the verb?

Tags: grammaticality, correlative-comparatives, flow

When using comparative correlatives in the context of something "being", can the verb be omitted?

A classic example of this is "The more, the merrier.", where we refrain are are "The more [there are], the merrier [we are]." That being said, this is an idiom, so perhaps the rules of the language are a bit more lax.

My question is, can the same verb-free construction be used in a more formal setting? For example: "The higher the value of x, the greater the effect." (having spoken about "x" and "the effect" in previous sentences).

I am a bit thrown off, as there are no (explicit) verbs, but including "is" loses the flow a little bit in my opinion. What's the consensus?

Thank you.

Comment: Of the comparative correlations (I didn't know there was a term for that) that I can recall, none of them explicitly include a state of "being" in the second part. E.g. The bigger they are, the harder they fall.

Comment: Omitting the verb "be" is possible in cases where the comparative phrase is a predicative AdjP. Expressions like "The sooner, the better" and "The sooner you leave the firm", the better" are common enough.